# CSS: Element slides over text

Tags: css

I am pretty new to css. I have defined a dot element with different collors.

```
/*Dots*/
.ccrdot {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ccrdot.red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.ccrdot.yellow {
  background-color: #fffb09;
}

.ccrdot.green {
  background-color: #67ff09;
}
```

But when i use this like:

```
> <span class="ccrdot"></span><span>Text Text Text</span>

<span class="ccrdot"></span> Text Text
```

or

```
<div class="ccrdot"></div> Text Text
```

The text slides under the dot element. I want to present them side by side. What did i do wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: remove absolute position

Comment: Works :) Thank you very much!

Comment: If so, please self-answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: absolute` takes them out of the text flow, so there's no space reserved for them anymore, if you remove it they'll have their own space.

```
/*Dots*/
.ccrdot {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ccrdot.red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.ccrdot.yellow {
  background-color: #fffb09;
}

.ccrdot.green {
  background-color: #67ff09;
}
```